# ScrollViewer 's scrollbar always disabled

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, scrollviewer

My xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="155"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="88*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Rectangle Height="800">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </ScrollViewer>
...
```

I've looked some solutions on this site about my problem, but none of them works. The scrollbar is enabled, and it appears enabled on the preview, but always disabled on runtime.

Did i miss something??

Comment: Your code is working fine in my case.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Now thats weird, what is your IDE? mine Visual Studio 2k17 Community

Comment: Mine is 2012 professional. I used ur code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed height on `Rectangle` that is inside the `ScrollViewer`so the scrollbar is not required because rectangle is not sizeable. This is the answer

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="155">
        <Rectangle Height="800">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: My bad, in your code the `grid` dictates that the row cannot be higher than 155. So your code should be perfectly fine and I'm also using VS 17 Community. https://imgur.com/a/UBHtP
I've changed the code a little, try it